# Eliminar Token de FCM

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, tokens

Hola tengo un problema con las notificaciones push usando FIREBASE CLOUD MESSAGING, en concreto el dar de baja un Token tras presionar un botón y así dejar de recibir las notificaciones. Así que mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo dar de baja un token o dispositvo del servicio?, he estado intentando usar:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId(); 
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()
      .deleteToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(),null);
```

pero ningún método me ha funcionado

dejo el código de mis clases:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button sa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sa);

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    sa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("test");


            try {
                //FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
               // FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(),null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Borrado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

FirebaseInstanceIDService

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    registerToken(token);


}

private void registerToken(String token) {

   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Token", token)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.0.107:8080/android/notificacion/registro.php")
            .post(body)
            .build();
    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 }
```

FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}

private void showNotification(String message) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Nueva Notificación")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default_img)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar, Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que al eliminar el token es solo cuestión de tiempo para que se vuelva a generar.

Para resolver tu problema deberías definir una [propiedad de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties) por ejemplo "OptedOutNotifications" y setearlo en true para los que lo decidan de esa manera.
Con esa propiedad funcionando puedes filtrar el envío de notificaciones para los usuarios que la tengan en un valor determinado.